# TypeScript server add `type` to imports?

Tags: typescript

How do you get the TypeScript server to add `type` imports automatically? I have a tsconfig.json with `isolatedModules`, but when the TS server automatically adds imports for me, the `type` prefix is not included.

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#importing-types

Can you configure TS in such a way that the TS server will include `type`?

### Example code

package.json

```
{
  "name": "tsimports",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "typescript": "^5.1.3"
  }
}
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2016",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true
  }
}
```

types.ts

```
export type Foo = {
  foo: number;
}

export const enum Enums {
  Up = 1,
  Down,
  Left,
  Right,
}
```

main.ts

```
// these imports were created by TS server
import {Enums, Foo} from "./types";

const foo: Foo = { foo: 1 }
const dir: Enums = Enums.Left;
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, the TypeScript server does not include the type prefix when automatically adding imports. However, you can use an editor extension or a separate tool to add the type prefix to the automatically added imports. For example, the typescript-tslint-plugin supports this feature.

To use the typescript-tslint-plugin, you can install it via npm and add it to your tsconfig.json file as a plugin:

> npm install typescript-tslint-plugin --save-dev

json

```
> {   "compilerOptions": {
>     ...
>     "plugins": [
>       {
>         "name": "typescript-tslint-plugin"
>       }
>     ]   } }
```

Comment: Thanks! It does seem quite odd that this isn's supported by the server directly, as that is just the type of thing implied by isolated modules.

Comment: Since that plugin has been replaced by `typescript-eslint`, here are the relevant details for configuring it accordingly: https://typescript-eslint.io/blog/consistent-type-imports-and-exports-why-and-how/#isolated-module-transpilation

Comment: Attempting to use eslint for this is causing errors. Wondering if there's another way?